# Is it possible to reduce the long-distance train fare in Norway?

Tags: budget, trains, norway

I want to travel from Kristiansand to Trondheim and back in the end of August.
[Looking up the itinerary](https://www.nsb.no/en/bestill/velg-togavgang?passengerType1=1&to=1126000&bookingPassengerExtrasPetfree=0&portable=false&bookingPassengerExtrasStroller=0&passengerCard1=&bookingPassengerExtrasClosetodog=0&hour=6&from=2130000&date=22.08.2014&type=return&returnDate=25.08.2014&passengers=1&bookingPassengerExtrasAnimalsallowed=0&returnHour=8&booking-submit-form=View%20train%20times%20and%20fares&redirect_to=https://www.nsb.no/en/bestill/velg-togavgang) for a random date in August shows that this will cost me around €60 for a two way ticket.

Is there a possibility to reduce that price with some special ticket? I'm thinking along the lines of an [Eurail](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes) pass or something like the German [weekend ticket](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/USA/en/prices/germany/happy_weekend_ticket.shtml).

Comment: You are aware that the prices on the page you're linking to is in Norwegian kroner and not in euro? You can get a return ticket for 498 kroner (about 61 euro), which is pretty fair for 800km one way.

Comment: Haha, that's quite a fail on my side. Thanks for pointing it out. While this changes the price a lot, the question is still valid I think.

Comment: I don't know if your question is still valid. The full price ticket is 2440 kroner, you've already found the cheapest offer yourself for 498 kroner and still want it cheaper? There are of course other options than taking the train. Hitch-hiking, walking or going by bike will probably be cheaper.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo As I'm not familiar with the Norwegian railway system I've no clue if I found the cheapest offer or not, that's why I ask. If you're sure it can't get cheaper you're welcome to post that as an answer. I don't considerd hitch-hiking, biking or walking as that takes ages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found the cheapest possible train ticket for that journey. Note that in order to get that price, you need to book well in advance.

There are [no weekend passes for long-distance trains](https://www.nsb.no/togbilletter/periodebillett-reisekort) <sup>(in Norwegian only)</sup>.

The cheapest available InterRail pass will [cost you €190](http://www.interrail.eu/interrail-passes/one-country-pass/norway) (or €129 if you're under 26).

All passenger train services in Norway, except the Airport Express train, are operated by Norwegian State Railways (NSB).

There are, to my knowledge, no other ways of purchasing a Kristiansand - Trondheim train ticket.

Comment: Probably not on this route, but there are other companies operating passenger train services in Norway as well.

Comment: Oh yes, the traffic going to Sweden might be other companies. Are there any others?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal How far in advance do you need to book?

Comment: @Danger14 Depends.  The number of low-fare tickets is limited, so in high traffic seasons they are gone early.